# Modo F11 no navegador

Tags: javascript, fullscreen

Existe alguma maneira de fazer com que o site, quando for carregado automaticamente, fique em tela cheia igual quando apertamos <kbd>F11</kbd>, em qualquer navegador?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar o js para na hora de carregar a página fazer o click no botão.

```
function toggleFullScreen(elem) {
        // ## The below if statement seems to work better ## if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) || (document.msfullscreenElement && document.msfullscreenElement !== null) || (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if ((document.fullScreenElement !== undefined && document.fullScreenElement === null) || (document.msFullscreenElement !== undefined && document.msFullscreenElement === null) || (document.mozFullScreen !== undefined && !document.mozFullScreen) || (document.webkitIsFullScreen !== undefined && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
            if (elem.requestFullScreen) {
                elem.requestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
                elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        } else {
            if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
                document.cancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
                document.msExitFullscreen();
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" value="click to toggle fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen(document.body)">
```

CSS

```
*:fullscreen
*:-ms-fullscreen,
*:-webkit-full-screen,
*:-moz-full-screen {
   overflow: auto !important;
}
```

Exemplo de https://jsfiddle.net/a3rwnvca/2/

Answer (score 3):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Felizmente** isso não é possível sem que haja uma interação prévia do usuário (ex. `click`, `keypress`, `keydown`). É um bloqueio nativo dos navegadores que impede que o código da página manipule o comportamento da janela.

Você pode usar o código fornecido nas outras respostas, mas terá que criar, por exemplo, um botão para que o usuário clique nele.

Answer (score 2):

Há uma Api de FullScreen:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

```
var elem = document.body;
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```